# Why are many of the characters of a string change when copied/pasted in JavaScript or assigned to a form input element

Tags: javascript, string

I have built the following string in JavaScript using the `String.fromCharCode` function and assigned it to variable `h`.

`var h=String.fromCharCode(127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146)`

When I print the string using `console.log`, the a space and 19 boxes show up (there are 20 characters in the string).

Now if I select these characters, copy them and paste them in a Hex Editor it shows the following:

`7F 3F 81 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 8D 3F 8F 90 3F 3F`

which are the ASCII codes for the characters in the given string.

`7F` is ok, but `3F` is wrong, it should have been `80`, `81` is correct but next `11` character are shown as `3F`, then `8D` but the next character code is again `3F` then next 2 character i.e `8F` and `90` are fine but next 2 character are again wrong.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening? `h.charCodeAt(1)` shows `128` though.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Exactly what "hex editor" are we talking about here?

Comment: The representation has been changed to UTF-8 when you copy and paste.

Comment: Why did you remove the original string output from the question?

Comment: its XVI32 Hex editor

Comment: @Barmar it was replaced by some strange characters when I submitted

Comment: How can I put them in a html form input element which being changed to UTF-8?

Comment: You can't. The browser converts everything to Unicode internally, the original character codes you used are not remembered.

Comment: Why do you care, as long as you get the same text?

Comment: If you're trying to pass binary data around, don't put it in a text element.

Comment: When this string is built it will be shown in a text box on an html form, I will then copy it and paste it in another software in this original form. But when I paste it there many of the characters change to 3F.

Comment: Some of them don't change, I don't understand the logic why some characters are not changed?

Comment: Code units below 128 have a single-byte UTF-8 representation (and the single byte is the same byte).

Comment: Yes I understand that above 127 UTF-8 has multi byte representation, String.fromCharCode(128) will give you a non-printable character shown as small box. if you copy that box and paste is somewhere see its code it will read 0x3F. Now if you do that same thing with String.fromCharCode(129) it gives you 0x81.